# Line2D.Double telling me lines are intersecting when they don't

Tags: java, line-intersection

In making a project for class, we are defining shapes (triangle, quadrilateral, pentagon) without the help of the `Shape` class obviously.

In my checks to make sure the shape is valid, I use `Line2D.Double linesIntersect()` to determine if the connections between two sets of points `(p1-p4 x p2-p3)`. When I have my input to `linesIntersect(double,double,double,double,etc)` set to:

```
p1(-1,-1)
p2(-1,-11)
p3(5,0)
p4(5,5)
```

It tells me that the line from `p1` to `p4` crosses the line from `p2` to `p3`. When in fact they should be two diagonal parallel lines.

Any help?

Comment: Sample code, or it didn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but based on what you typed, p1, p4 is not parallel to p2, p3.

```
p1(-1,-1)
p4(5,5)

p2(-1,-11)
p3(5,0)
```

p1, p4 has a slope of 1.

p2, p3 has a slope of 11/6 or 1.83

If you want the lines to be parallel, then you need to change p3.

```
p3(5,-5)
```

Comment: true, my bad, but the fact still remains that the two lines start and end at the points and at no point do they intersect.
We did end up finding out what was wrong in our use of linesIntersect(), thank you for the response!

Comment: @user1231771: I think the intersect method assumes the lines extend past their end points.